# Is explicit static_cast required for nuneric function return value?

Tags: c++, casting

For example, I would like to saturate cast a signed char value `v`, to an unsigned value.
Is there any difference for the following two implementations? One is without explicit static cast, the other is with.

```cpp
unsigned char saturate_cast_to_uchar(signed char v)
{
    return std::max(static_cast<int>(v), 0);
}
```

```cpp
unsigned char saturate_cast_to_uchar(signed char v)
{
    return static_cast<unsigned char>(std::max(static_cast<int>(v), 0));
}
```

Comment: I'd probably use `std::max(v, static_cast<signed char>(0))` instead

Comment: `std::max<unsigned char>(v, 0)`. Look, ma, no casts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any difference for the following two implementations?

There is no difference in the behaviour. Implicit conversion from `int` to `unsigned char` has exactly the same behaviour as static cast from `int` to `unsigned char`

Comment: Implicit conversion from int to uchar often sets off warnings.